Custom Page View Event is Not Working
I am trying to save custom page events as mentioned in this document https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/convert-a-page-event.html.
Below is my code:
I have created ConvertPageEventDataToCustomPageViewEvent class.
 public class ConvertPageEventDataToCustomPageViewEvent : ConvertPageEventDataToEventBase
    {
        protected override bool CanProcessPageEventData(Sitecore.Analytics.Model.PageEventData pageEventData)
        {
            if (pageEventData.PageEventDefinitionId == Guid.Parse("{CD52B756-21B4-4028-8BA5-E981B8A96F95}"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected override Event CreateEvent(Sitecore.Analytics.Model.PageEventData pageEventData)
        {
            var number = pageEventData.CustomValues["Number"]?.ToString();
            var tabName = pageEventData.CustomValues["TabName"]?.ToString();
            var startTime = pageEventData.CustomValues["StartTime"]?.ToString();
             var timeSpan="some logic";     

            CustomPageViewEvent ev = new CustomPageViewEvent(pageEventData.DateTime, pageEventData.ItemId, 1, "en", pageEventData.DataKey, pageEventData.Data, number , tabName, timeSpan);
          
            return ev;
        }
    }

On some button click I am registering for the event.
 var ev = Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents[new Guid("{CD52B756-21B4-4028-8BA5-E981B8A96F95}")];

                if (ev != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(number) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    var pageData = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.PageEventData(ev.Alias, ev.Id);
                    pageData.CustomValues.Add("Number", number);
                    pageData.CustomValues.Add("TabName", name);
                    pageData.CustomValues.Add("StartTime", DateTime.Now);
                    Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(pageData);
                }

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <convertToXConnectEvent>
                <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToEvent, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect']"
                type="XYZ.ConvertPageEventDataToCustomPageViewEvent, XYZ"/>
            </convertToXConnectEvent>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>



public static class CustomPageViewEventModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            var modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("CustomPageViewEventModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

            modelBuilder.DefineEventType<CustomPageViewEvent>(true);

            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentManagement or ContentDelivery or Standalone or Reporting or Processing">
    <xconnect>
      <runtime
        type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
        <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
          <!-- value of 'name' property must be unique -->
         
            <schema name="customageviewomodel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
                <param desc="modeltype">XYZ.CustomPageViewEventModel, XYZ</param>
            </schema>
            
        </schemas>
      </runtime>
    </xconnect>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Also, I have deployed JSON.
The problem is that convertToXConnectEvent pipeline is not calling. I have checked the show config is correct.

Are you testing against cd or standalone?

It is a standalone

I have created pipeline to register events
public class RegisterCustomPageEvents : ProcessItemProcessor
    {
        string PAGEEVENTID = "GUID";
        public override void Process(ProcessItemArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));

            foreach (TrackingField trackingParameter in (IEnumerable<TrackingField>)args.TrackingParameters)
            {
                TrackingFieldProcessor.ProcessEvents(args.Interaction, trackingParameter);
            }

            if (!Tracker.Enabled || Tracker.Current == null || !Tracker.Current.IsActive)
            {
                return;
            }

            RegisterCustomPageViewEvent(args);
        }

        private void RegisterCustomPageViewEvent(ProcessItemArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Item == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var customPageEventId = Guid.Parse(PAGEEVENTID);
            var eventDefinition = Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents[customPageEventId];

            if (eventDefinition == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var pageData = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.PageEventData(eventDefinition.Alias, eventDefinition.Id);
            pageData.Text = "sometext";
            pageData.CustomValues["TabName"] = "tabname";
            pageData.CustomValues["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;
            pageData.CustomValues["Number"] = "somevalue";
            pageData.ItemId = args.Item.ID.ToGuid();
          
            try
            {
                var interaction = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction;
                var EventSourceItem = interaction.CurrentPage.PageEvents.Any(pe => pe.PageEventDefinitionId == customPageEventId);
                if (!EventSourceItem)
                {
                    Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(pageData);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Unable to fire custom page event: {ex.Message}", ex, this);
            }
        }
    }

<processItem>
 <processor type="XYZ.RegisterCustomPageEvents, XYZ" />
</processItem>

After that when session is ending I am able to see custom events in Interaction table.

You will also need to deploy custom page event created above to XConnect roles through XdbModelBuilder. Model to be deployed can be built using below code:
public class CustomEventModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = CustomEventModel.BuildModel();
        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("CustomEventModel", new XdbModelVersion(0, 1));
            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
            modelBuilder.DefineEventType<CustomPageViewEvent>(false);
            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }

Once the above model is built, you can deploy its json and dll file to XConnect and core roles.
You can see the custom event created in the Shards database inside the Interactions table as below.

Note: Data for the custom event will be stored in the Events column inside Interactions table.
More details can be found here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-custom-event-model.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-a-custom-model.html
Hope this helps!!!

Thanks for the response. I already have deployed JSON and deployed model. I have added code into question.

@SwatiGupta I have made the same changes and deployed custom event model. It then works as expected as shown above. Can you check if you missed any deployment in any of the roles as mentioned in this doc https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-a-custom-model.html.

Thanks, I have added answer below, after adding code in pipeline it is working.
